# Simplifying/Factoring a polynomial via certain given smaller polynomials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have a complicated polynomial with integer coefficients and variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_n$, say
$$
-x_2^2 y_1 y_3+x_1 x_2 y_4^2+x_3 x_2 y_1 y_2+x_1 x_2 y_2 y_3-x_4
   x_2 y_1 y_4-x_1 x_3 y_2^2+x_4^2 y_1 y_2-x_1 x_4 y_2 y_4
$$
or in code

```
expr=-Subscript[x, 2]^2*Subscript[y, 1]*Subscript[y, 3] + 
   Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 4]^2 + 
   Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 1]*
     Subscript[y, 2] + Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*
     Subscript[y, 2]*Subscript[y, 3] - 
   Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 1]*
     Subscript[y, 4] - Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 3]*
     Subscript[y, 2]^2 + Subscript[x, 4]^2*Subscript[y, 1]*
     Subscript[y, 2] - Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 4]*
     Subscript[y, 2]*Subscript[y, 4]
```

And I *know* that it factors via polynomials $(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)$. For example the above polynomials is
$$\left(x_1 y_2-x_2 y_1\right) \left(x_2 y_3-x_3 y_2\right)+\left(x_1 y_4-x_4 y_1\right) \left(x_2 y_4-x_4 y_2\right)$$
or in code:

```
(Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[y, 2] - Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 1])*(Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 3] - Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[y, 2]) + 
  (Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[y, 4] - Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[y, 1])*(Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 4] - Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[y, 2])
```

In other words my polynomial is known to have a form $\sum_{i=1}^m c_if_i$ with $f_i$ of the form $\prod_{k=1}^\ell(x_{i_k}y_{j_k}-x_{j_k}y_{i_k})$ and $c_i$ an integer.

Is there a way mathematica simplifies my polynomial in a form like above? This is similar to what `SymmetricReduction` command does, which takes a polynomial and breaks it down into elementary symmetric polynomials. Symmetric reduction also gives the remainder but I don't need that. I might need to mention that the actual polynomials I have are *gigantic!* (it takes mathematica a second just to show it all).

**Edit** I thought about constructing a set of rules (in our example `n=4`)

```
rules = Flatten[
  Table[Subscript[x, i] Subscript[y, j] - Subscript[x, j] Subscript[y, i] ->
 Subscript[Z, i, j],{i, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]]
```

But this doesn't work... I think I need to include all of the rules $(x_iy_j-x_iy_j)^p=Z_{ij}^p$ that might appear in the expression together with $-(x_iy_j-x_iy_j)=-Z_{ij}$, because as it is nothing happens when I apply these rules by `expr/.rules`.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 is it better now? Sorry I'm a frequent math.SE user so using TeX in this platform comes as a habit to me. You're right though...

Comment: Perhaps there's some sense in which the factored polynomials that appear in the sum are orthogonal? That would make this "factorization" straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

General remark: All this would cut-paste nicer if variables were indexed rather than subscripted e.g. y[1]. I do not have the patience to deal with reformatting all this as I go between Mathematica and MSE.

In general such things can be done using `PolynomialReduce`, possibly with some preprocessing. In this case it is quite straightforward. We set up the expression.

```
expr = -Subscript[x, 2]^2*Subscript[y, 1]*Subscript[y, 3] + 
  Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 4]^2 + 
  Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 1]*Subscript[y, 2] + 
  Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 2]*Subscript[y, 3] - 
  Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 1]*Subscript[y, 4] - 
  Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[y, 2]^2 + 
  Subscript[x, 4]^2*Subscript[y, 1]*Subscript[y, 2] - 
  Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[y, 2]*Subscript[y, 4];
```

Now define the replacements as rules (we use them in a more fundamental way as polynomials, but this makes it easier to convert between rules and expressions). The idea is to recast the desired replacements as new variables. `PolynomialReduce` can then be used to rewrite the expression, to the extent possible, in terms of these new variables.

```
replacementrules = {p1 -> (Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[y, 2] - 
       Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[y, 1])*(Subscript[x, 2]*
        Subscript[y, 3] - Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[y, 2]), 
   p2 -> (Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[y, 4] - 
       Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[y, 1])*(Subscript[x, 2]*
        Subscript[y, 4] - Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[y, 2])};
replacementpolys = replacementrules /. Rule :> Subtract

(* Out[31]= {p1 - (-Subscript[4, 2] Subscript[y, 1] + 
     Subscript[4, 1] Subscript[y, 2]) (-Subscript[4, 3] Subscript[y, 
      2] + Subscript[4, 2] Subscript[y, 3]), 
 p2 - (-Subscript[4, 4] Subscript[y, 1] + 
     Subscript[4, 1] Subscript[y, 4]) (-Subscript[4, 4] Subscript[y, 
      2] + Subscript[4, 2] Subscript[y, 4])} *)
```

Now we use `PolynomialReduce` as advertised. We specify the variables in the original expression, and any others (in particular the "new" variables) get ordered lower so that the reduced expression will use them in preference to the original variables. When done, do the back-substitution. In effect this uses the replacement rules to go in reverse.

```
PolynomialReduce[expr, replacementpolys, 
   Variables[expr]][[2]] /. replacementrules

(* Out[32]= (-Subscript[4, 2] Subscript[y, 1] + 
    Subscript[4, 1] Subscript[y, 2]) (-Subscript[4, 3] Subscript[y, 
     2] + Subscript[4, 2] Subscript[y, 
     3]) + (-Subscript[4, 4] Subscript[y, 1] + 
    Subscript[4, 1] Subscript[y, 4]) (-Subscript[4, 4] Subscript[y, 
     2] + Subscript[4, 2] Subscript[y, 4]) *)
```

Comment: Do you have any comments on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128444/12)?  Is it safe?  Appropriate?  The usual way?  I'm not experiences with it and even though I posted it in the form of an answer, what I was really expecting is comments from others.

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems safe enough and I see nothing inappropriate about it. I do not know what would be the usual way though.