# How can I define a new symbolic constant like Pi?

Tags: numerics, symbolic, language-design

There are a few builtin symbolic constants which behave like numbers, e.g. `E`, `Pi`, `EulerGamma`, etc.

How can I define my own in such a way that the system will treat them just like the builtin ones?

Answer (score 45):

I was recently reminded that the following "functions" are settable, and I was surprised (even though I've seen this before).  So I thought that it is valuable to share this information.

There are three critical properties of symbolic constants:

- The [`Constant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Constant.html) attribute, which is used by [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html)
- The ability to tell that it is a numeric expression (`NumericQ[Pi] === True`).
- The ability to compute the value to any precision.

We can implement all three by direct assignment.  Let the symbol `sqrt2` represent $\sqrt{2}$:

```
SetAttributes[sqrt2, Constant]
NumericQ[sqrt2] = True;
N[sqrt2, prec___] := N[Sqrt[2], prec]
```

Note that it wasn't necessary to unprotect any symbols.

Now `sqrt2` doesn't evaluate:

```
sqrt2
(* sqrt2 *)
```

But it can be computed numerically:

```
N[sqrt2, 100]
(* 1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573 *)
```

It is numeric:

```
NumericQ[sqrt2]
(* True *)
```

Which means that many functions work well with it without the need for additional definitions:

```
Positive[sqrt2]
(* True *)

Im[sqrt2]
(* 0 *)

Integrate[Exp[-sqrt2 x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* 1/sqrt2 *)
```

Integrate wouldn't give the same result with an arbitrary symbolic parameter:

```
Integrate[Exp[-s x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/s, Re[s] > 0] *)
```

And of course it works with `Dt`

```
Dt[sqrt2 x, x]
(* sqrt2 *)
```

---

**Update:**  How do we clear such a symbol?  Like this:

```
ClearAll[sqrt2]
NumericQ[sqrt2] =.
```

I do not know where the `NumericQ` setting is stored.  It doesn't seem to be associated either with `NumericQ` or `sqrt2`.  Also, `NumericQ` is clearly set up to handle this usage and will not accept invalid values.

---

**Did I miss anything?  If so, let me know!**

Comment: …Where are `NumericQ[sqrt2] = True` and `N[sqrt2, prec___] := N[Sqrt[2], prec]` stored? Is executing `NumericQ[sqrt2] = False` the only way to "clear" the `NumericQ[sqrt2]=True`?

Comment: @xzczd Where is it stored?  I have no idea.  It doesn't seem to be associated either with `NumericQ` or `sqrt2`.  But I can tell you how to clear it: `NumericQ[sqrt2] =.`  If you asked the same question about `N` then the answer would be `NValues[sqrt2]`.

Comment: OK. Another "missing" truth: the `sqrt2` is compilable.

Comment: One thing this approach misses is missing relations. Mathematica knows for example that `Log[E] == 1` and `Sin[Pi] == 0`, but it doesn't know `sqrt2^2 == 2`. I suppose this is a case by case issue though...

Comment: @ChipHurst Does it look reasonable otherwise?  You work with this directly, I just play until I manage to get something working ... Do you have any tips on how to make it better and do tricks like `1 + 1/GoldenRatio == GoldenRatio` evaluating to `True` even without a `Simplify`?  I tried teaching `FunctionExpand` that `sqrt2 -> Sqrt[2]` just like it knows that `GoldenRatio -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on other functions (not even `FullSimplify`)

Comment: @Szabolcs I *think* achieving full system integration like `GoldenRatio` is impossible top level. I believe there are some flags set low level that users just plain can't access.

Comment: Though through spelunking, one can find that `FunctionExpand` (and therefore `FullSimplify`) can be taught rules by adding them to ``SimplifyDump`$FSTab`` and your symbol can be hooked in by adding your symbol to ``SimplifyDump`PositiveRules``.

Comment: @ChipHurst Can you explain in details how those internals of `SimplifyDump` work, for example, what is the relation between the rhs of the rule in `PositiveRules` and the (negative?) parameter of `$FSTab`? Also how to enter backquote in code?

Comment: When clearing could you remove the need to `Unset` `NumericQ[sqrt2]` by using `UpSet`? `NumericQ[sqrt2] ^= True`