# Why ClearAll[n] does not clear effect of NumericQ[n]=True

Tags: clear

To solve some PDE, I have to set `NumericQ[n]=True` on some symbol to get a solution, else Mathematica will not solve it.

When I tried `ClearAll[n]` later on, above command effect was not removed.

I need to clear it, so that later commands do not fail, since now doing `n>0` will fail because I did `NumericQ[n]=True` before.

Doing `ClearAll[n]` have no effect. It still fails.

Here is a MWE

```
(*new kernel *)
NumericQ[n]=True;
n>0
   Greater::nord2: Comparison of n and 0 is invalid.
```

Ok, Mathematica does not like to compare `n` with zero. So I do

```
ClearAll[n];
```

And try again

```
n>0  (*still gives same error as above*)
```

I looked at `OwnValues@n` and  `UpValues@n` and `DownValues@n` and `SubValues@n` and they all give `{}`

One way I found is to do `NumericQ[n]=False;` and this works. But I do not understand why `ClearAll[n]` does not work.

Thanks to comment below by Anjan Kumar `Remove[n]` also removes the effect.

*My question is*, why `ClearAll[n]` did not work?

Mathematica 11.3 on windows.

Comment: Perhaps `Remove[n]`?

Comment: @AnjanKumar thanks, `Remove` works. But do you know why `ClearAll` does not work? May be I'll change the question to why clearAll does not work.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128445/1871

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can undo this using

```
NumericQ[n] =.
```

(Note that there is no space between the `=` and the `.`)

`ClearAll` does not work because the definition is not associated with the symbol `n`.  It seems that in this case it is not even associated with the symbol `NumericQ`.  I believe that assignment operators are specially overloaded for `NumericQ`, and trying to make an assignment will cause the system to store away this information somewhere else.

`Remove` works because it effectively destroys the symbol `n`. So wherever this information about `n` was stored, `n` will be removed from there.

---

Here's an example of how I imagine `NumericQ` *might* work. This may of course be entirely wrong, but it illustrates one possible reason for why `ClearAll` wouldn't remove this setting.

```
Unprotect[spec];
ClearAll[spec, registry];
registry = <||>;
spec /: (Set | SetDelayed)[spec[sym_Symbol], val : True | False] := (AssociateTo[registry, sym -> val]; val)
spec /: Unset[spec[sym_Symbol]] := (KeyDropFrom[registry, sym];)
spec[sym_Symbol] := Lookup[registry, sym, False]
Protect[spec];
```

Demonstration:

```
spec[x] = True
(* True *)

ClearAll[x]

spec[x]
(* True *)

registry
(* <|x -> True|> *)
```

Comment: @Kuba How about now?

Comment: Now it clearly is :)