# How to define a function to be numeric when the input is purely symbolic

Tags: numerics, pattern-matching, numerical-value, attributes

My goal is to have NumericQ[h[j]]=True for any j regardless of whether j may be symbolic with no defined value.

Setting NumericQ[h[j_]]=True does not work and as I understand the NumericFunction attribute only works when the input is also numeric.

One solution might be to unprotect NumericQ and then set NumericQ[h[j_]]=True but I have not tried this as I am afraid of using Unprotect.
Another solution might be to define my own NumericQ function, that I can call numericq for example, and set numericq[h[j_]]=True but I would have to replace all previous NumericQ with numericq in my code and test that everything works.

- edit *

I want to do this because I want my code to ignore certain symbols. My solution was to treat these symbols as numeric but this does not work for symbols like h[j] when j is a generic symbol. Any other function that works like NumericQ could work although I would have to change my code a bit.

Comment: This gives off the impression of an XY problem. Surely there is a way to solve your *actual* problem that does not involve doing fragile things like redefining `NumericQ[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I agree that my question is on my current solution rather than the problem. I added an edit under * edit * to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Instead of unprotecting `NumericQ`, you could use an [upvalue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) as in `h/:HoldPattern[NumericQ[h[_]]]=True`. I am not saying that it is a good idea. Btw: Somewhat surprisingly to me, even something like `NumericQ[undefinedsymbol]=True` gives no error. I do not understand why it gives no error, `NumericQ` is protected, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @user293787,  that is a slick solution. I did not think of using an upvalue. I am quite inexperienced with upvalues. If you want to copy-paste your comment into a solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of unprotecting `NumericQ`, one can define an [upvalue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) for `h`:

```
h/:HoldPattern[NumericQ[h[_]]]=True;
```

This means that the definition is stored with `h` rather than with `NumericQ`:

```
UpValues[h]
(* {HoldPattern[HoldPattern[NumericQ[h[_]]]]:>True} *)
```

When an expression such as `NumericQ[h[4]]` is evaluated, then upvalue definitions for `h` are tried before downvalue definitions for `NumericQ`, hence we get `True`. See [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions).

**Warning.** Though I have used upvalues before with `NumericQ`, I do not know if it can break something.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an extended comment and not strictly an answer. But I thought I put this here, since people that end up here for whatever reason might find it useful. For reference, I am currently using Version 12.3.*

While writing the other answer, I was surprised to find that the assignment

```
NumericQ[undefinedsymbol] = True
```

gives no warning, despite `NumericQ` having the attribute `Protected`. And it works, meaning now

```
NumericQ[undefinedsymbol]
(* gives True *)
```

By contrast

```
NumericQ[undefinedsymbol2] = "seriously"
```

gives the error message

> Cannot set NumericQ[undefinedsymbol2] to seriously; the lhs argument must be a symbol and the rhs must be True or False

This error would suggest that

```
NumericQ[undefinedsymbol3[789]] = True
```

would fail since `undefinedsymbol3[789]` is not a symbol, but it gives no error or warning. However,

```
NumericQ[undefinedsymbol3[789]]
(* gives False *)
```

I find this a bit misleading. Probably `NumericQ[undefinedsymbol3[789]] = True` should give an error, since without error, one assumes that the definition was recorded, when in fact it was not.

I do not know if people use this feature of `NumericQ`. I do not see it mentioned in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html).

**Comment.** I can understand how `NumericQ[undefinedsymbol] = True` can work despite the protection. For example, `NumericQ` could be using something similar to the following code to circumvent the protection:

```
myNumericQ/:Set[myNumericQ[x_Symbol],tf:(True|False)]:=(
   Unprotect[myNumericQ];
   AppendTo[DownValues[myNumericQ],HoldPattern[myNumericQ[x]]:>tf];
   Protect[myNumericQ];
   tf);
Protect[myNumericQ];
```

Comment: As far as I know NumericQ[symbol]=True is a well-known way to attach the numeric property to a symbol and as far as I know, it is a mystery how it works.  Szabolcs discusses his guess [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/168023/86543) where he also discusses why ClearAll[symbol] does not remove the numeric property from symbol.

Comment: @userrandrand Thank you very much, I had not seen that post! I see that Scabolcs' guess for how it works is similar to mine (but maybe mine has some obvious flaw, not sure). I think I will leave the post here for now, if only to point out the questionable behavior for `NumericQ[undefinedsymbol3[789]] = True`.

Comment: For a better alternative to the `AppendTo` used above, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271431/85954).