# How to automatically interrupt `Set` with conditions

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Maybe this is a bad idea: I want to inject some conditions into `Set` associated to specfic symbols, like

```
clear@{f,g}
f/:Set[f[x_],y_]:=
    If[
        !IntegerQ@x,
        Print["non-integer"],
        (*pre-codes;*)
        f[x]=y;
        (*post-codes;*)
    ]
```

but this try fails:

```
Set[f[1],2]
(*
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
Hold[f[1]=2]
*)
```

I also tried (but failed) adding some pre-codes and post-codes (like `ValueQ`) to escape from the infinite loop, except trivially changing `Set` to some other symbol like,

```
fSet[f[x_],y_]:=
    If[
        !IntegerQ@x,
        Print["non-integer"],
        f[x]=y;
    ]
```

Are there other ways to solve this problem, or should I abandon this idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a standard trick for dealing with this problem! It involves setting up a so-called *intercept*, and is a general way to avoid using the same definition you're creating within the definition:

```
setInterceptf = True;
Protect[setInterceptf];

f /: Set[f[x_], y_] /; setInterceptf :=
  Block[{setInterceptf = False},
    If[!IntegerQ@x, Print["non-integer"], f[x] = y]
   ]
```

This way, the definition applies by default (since `setInterceptf` is globally `True`)—but inside the definition, the external definition won't get used, since `setInterceptf` will be `False`.

You'll have to have an extra global symbol here, but we `Protect`ed it just in case, so it shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: This is clearly a very flexible approach!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `f[x]=y` one could try

```
   AppendTo[DownValues[f],HoldPattern[f[x]]:>y];
```

But as OP correctly points out, manual management of `DownValues` has disadvantages.

Comment: Thx! But it seems that using this method we also need to further modify the list `DownValues`. For example, after `f[1]=a;f[1]=b` two downvalues will be kept, and we need to care about the order.

Comment: I agree. Manual management of `DownValues` is possible but probably not a good idea in general. The solution using an intercept is certainly the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for any hocus locus here, just make the condition part of the pattern:

```
f /: Set[f[x_], y_] /; !IntegerQ[x] := (
    Print @ "not an integer";
    $Failed (* or nothing here and Print returns Null *)
)
```

It works as expected:

```
In[28]:= f[2] = 3

Out[28]= 3

In[29]:= f[2.2] = 5

During evaluation of In[29]:= not an integer

Out[29]= $Failed
```