# How to define a named constant with evaluation rules similar to GoldenRatio?

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, evaluation, symbolic

I want to define a named constant standing for a more complicated symbolic expression, for example, `PlasticConstant` for the [plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html):

```
((9 - √69)^(1/3) + (9 + √69)^(1/3))/(2^(1/3) 3^(2/3))
```

and I want it to have evaluation rules similar to [`GoldenRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoldenRatio.html):

- it remains in its named form during normal evaluation (so, simple `Set` does not solve my problem);
- it can be numerically evaluated to an arbitrary precision using `N`;
- it can be converted to the underlying expression in radicals by `FunctionExpand`, can be converted to a `Root` object by `RootReduce`;
- `FullSimplify` is able to replace it with its underlying expression when it helps reducing overall complexity of a containing expression, but leaves it in its named form otherwise;

Equality and inequality operators between the named constant and its underlying expression should automatically evaluate to Boolean values:

```
PlasticConstant == ((9 - √69)^(1/3) + (9 + √69)^(1/3))/(2^(1/3) 3^(2/3))
(* True *)
```

similar to how it happens here:

```
GoldenRatio == (1 + √5)/2
(* True *)
```

How can we do it?

Comment: Related [(128444)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128444/45431). It doesn't cover FunctionExpand, RootReduce or FullSimplify.

Comment: I'd try it with upvalues, but I'm not sure which cases will suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather long for a comment:

I think the OP's goals are going to be hard to achieve.  `GoldenRatio` is embedded in the system in ways I don't know.  Here is some examples of the embedding that come from an internal [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) of `FunctionExpand@GoldenRation`:

```
GoldenRatio /. SimplifyDump`PositiveRules
SimplifyDump`$FSTab /@ %
(*
  {901}
  {GoldenRatio :> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}
*)
```

Some of the OP's goals can be handled programmatically.  For instance:

```
ClearAll[OneThird];
SetAttributes[OneThird, {Constant}];
N[OneThird, p_: MachinePrecision] := N[1/3, p];

OneThird // N[#, 22] &
(*  0.3333333333333333333333  *)
```

However, automatic conversion to its numerical value does not happen for `OneThird` as it does for `GoldenRatio`:

```
3. OneThird
3. GoldenRatio
(*
  3. OneThird
  4.8541
*)
```

Maybe someone else will know how to do it.  An internal trace reveals nothing.

Comment: You need `NumericQ[OneThird] = True` as in @Szabolcs' answer to the related question.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks.

Comment: Also, I usually do `N[OneThird, _] = 1/3` instead, but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: I think rules for `FunctionExpand` and `FullSimplify` can be added somehow via ```SimplifyDump`PositiveRules``` and ```SimplifyDump`$FSTab```. What do numeric indexes in the latter mean? What index do I use to add my own entry?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes, I think you're right.  The numbers are indices for `$FSTab`.  You can look at them with ``?SimplifyDump`$FSTab``.  Obviously you would use an index that is not present in ``Cases[DownValues[SimplifyDump`$FSTab], HoldPattern@SimplifyDump`$FSTab[n_Integer] :> n, Infinity]``. (I don't know for sure that any missing one is safe.)

Comment: It appears to work almost as I wanted, except that equalities/inequalities, `Element[PlasticConstant, Algebraics]` and `Abs[PlasticConstant - ((9 - √69)^(1/3) + (9 + √69)^(1/3))/(2^(1/3) 3^(2/3))]` are not evaluated automatically (although can be forced by `FullSimplify`), and `RootReduce` and `MinimalPolynomial` do not work unless `FunctionExpand` has been applied first. I'm still not sure if it is safe to use any unused index to add my rule to ```SimplifyDump`$FSTab``` and ```SimplifyDump`PositiveRules```.