# Creating my own function AtomQ and NumericQ

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I want to create my own functions `AtomQ` and `NumericQ`.
For example, I already create some functions (`IntegerQ`,`EvenQ`,`OddQ`,`PrimeQ`):

```
meuIntegerQ[_Integer] := True
meuIntegerQ[_] := False

meuEvenQ[n_Integer] /; Divisible[n, 2] := True
meuEvenQ[_] := False

meuOddQ[n_Integer] /; Divisible[n, 2] := True
meuOddQ[_] := False

meuPrimeQ[1] = False;
meuPrimeQ[2] = True;
meuPrimeQ[n_Integer /; n > 2] := Length[Divisors[n]] == 2
```

How can I create a function that does the same at `AtomQ` and `NumericQ` like the examples.

Ps: This is just for exercise.

Comment: What are the traits you expect out of something that gives `True` for `AtomQ`?

Comment: "yields `True` if expr is an expression which cannot be divided into subexpressions, and yields `False` otherwise. " @JasonB.

Comment: Just keep in mind that definition doesn't even really apply to `AtomQ`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to re-implement `AtomQ` and `NumericQ`?  It is not possible to do this perfectly. These functions are too deeply intertwined with the rest of Mathematica. E.g. did you know [you could assign to NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128445/12) and that it would affect other functions too?

Comment: "How can I create a function that does the same at AtomQ and NumericQ like the examples." In the strict sense, the answer is: you can't. If your actual question is: "What do these functons really do?" then please ask that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ) you could try:

```
numericQ[n_] := MatchQ[n//N, _Real|_Complex]
```

Example:

```
numericQ[Pi]
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt at recognizing atoms:

```
atomQ[x_] := Head[List @@ x] =!= List || Quiet[Head[x] @@ List @@ x =!= x]
```

First, try to `Apply` `List` to the expression. With non-atoms this yields a `List` of their content, but with the simpler atoms it silently fails, yielding the atom. If that happens, you have an atom. For complicated "atoms" like `SparseArray` and `Association`, this yields a `List`. For a normal, non-atomic object, this `List` is just the original object with a different `Head`, so you may reconstruct the original by `Apply`ing the original head. This fails, often noisily, with complex atoms, so that's the second test. `Quiet` suppresses the noise.

Answer (score 1):

> `AtomQ[expr]` yields `True` if `expr` is an expression which cannot be divided into subexpressions, and yields `False` otherwise.

A simple enough function,

```
atomQ[obj_] := Length[obj] === 0
```

That this sometimes disagrees with the system function `AtomQ` seems like an issue with the documentation.

Comment: `True` for non-atomic objects that are empty, like `{}`. `False` for complicated "atoms" like SparseArray and Association when they have contents. So, this doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnDoty If `SparseArray` and `Association` don't follow the documentation for `AtomQ`, I can't be blamed for that.

Comment: But the machinery to divide expressions into subexpressions doesn't work for `SparseArray` and `Association`. It yields data, but that data is incomplete, inadequate to reconstruct the original expression.

Comment: I stand by my answer to this question. I'm available in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica) if you want to talk more about the inconsistencies in the language.

Comment: It would be very sad if the following weren't true: `Length @ Range[10] == Length @ SparseArray @ Range[10].` Basically, some structural functions have been overloaded to handle atomic objects. This doesn't mean that the atomic object can be subdivided into subexpressions.

Comment: Then the documentation should be more explicit about what "subdivided" means.