# Wrong result using "numeric" symbols

Tags: numerics, evaluation

Recently I stumbled upon a weird bug when I used a package that sets the NumericQ result of symbols you are feeding into a certain function to true.

Here is a minimal working example of what I mean:

```
NumericQ[a] ^= True;
NumericQ[b] ^= True;
a + a (-1.`) - 2 b + 2.` 0 b + 2 b
```

The output of the above expression should be 0 but it gives

```
0. - 2 b
```

Exchanging any of the floats with integers gives the correct result. Could someone explain to me what is happening here? Is this a bug I should report?

Another hint could be that when I decrease the factor in front of the first b by one, the result is decreased by 2:

```
a + a (-1.`) - 3 b + 2.` 0 b + 2 b
```

yields

```
0. - 4 b
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: On the one hand, this is probably unexpected behavior. On the other hand: What is the point of setting `NumericQ[a]` to `True` if `a` is a symbol? This breaks the whole purpose of `NumericQ`.

Comment: It's used in this package: http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/. You can define real constants using snegrealconstants, so that for example functions like scalarproduct can distinguish between operators and scalars.

Comment: Well, that does not convince me that what they do were good practice.

Comment: If `N[x]` does not return a number then `NumericQ[x]` should *not* be `True`. This is simply a misuse of `NumericQ`.

Comment: Here is a reasonable use for adding definitions to `NumericQ`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128444/12 Using it to indicate what is a scalar and what is an operator is plainly wrong, and will lead to lots of broken things down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm not sure, if the author is using it for other purposes as well. So for a scalar indication I should just use Constant for example? But the question about what is happening that a wrong result is evaluated still remains.